# Post large amount of data with Wicket.ajax.post

Tags: ajax, post, file-upload, wicket

I'm trying to use the `Behavior` and JavaScript `FileReader` as can be seen in this question: [Wicket Drag and drop functionality for adding an image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13841444/461499)

If I post more than 200k, I get an error `Form too large`. So perhaps I am missing some multipart stuff.

What is the proper way to call `Wicket.ajax.post()` with a large amount of data?

I tried setting `mp` to `true`, but then it started complaining that I do not have a form id. Does it need a form?

Btw. I use Jetty, but that has no problems using a regular file upload using forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes from jetty `Request` implementation.

If you look at sources of the `Request#extractFormParameters` method, you will see next:

```
if (_context != null)
{
    maxFormContentSize = _context.getContextHandler().getMaxFormContentSize();
    maxFormKeys = _context.getContextHandler().getMaxFormKeys();
}

if (maxFormContentSize < 0)
{
   Object obj = _channel.getServer().getAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize");
   if (obj == null)
      maxFormContentSize = 200000;
   else if
      ...
}
```

So, in fact, you can really set your context values as pikand proposed as `0`, or set server config as follows:

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <Call name="setAttribute">
      <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize</Arg>
      <Arg>-1<!-- or 0, or any lt 0 --></Arg>
    </Call>
    ...
</Configure>
```

Your exception is thrown a bit later according to this code:

```
if (contentLength > maxFormContentSize && maxFormContentSize > 0)
{
    throw new IllegalStateException("Form too large: " + contentLength + " > " + maxFormContentSize);
}
```

So, you can see, that `maxFormContentSize` could be `<= 0` not to throw this exception.

I think, there is no need to update something via ajax. But in fact it is better to limit data size, not to allow users put down your server.

Other application servers have their own settings, for most of them you should set `maxPostSize` value to zero, to disable this restriction.

---

Also, wicket `Form` component has it's own `maxSize` property, you can set it with `Form#setMaxSize`. The problem is that `Form` transmittes this value as `Bytes` value to `FileUploadBase` class, which has next javadoc:

> The maximum size permitted for the complete request, as opposed to
>   fileSizeMax. A value of -1 indicates no maximum.

And actually this parameter is set via `fileUpload.setSizeMax(maxSize.bytes());`, and `Bytes` can't hold negative value. But I think you can try to set it as `0` and check if it works. By default, `Form#getSizeMax()` method checks:

```
return getApplication().getApplicationSettings().getDefaultMaximumUploadSize();
```

Which returns `Bytes.MAX`, which is equals to `8388608 terabytes`. I think, this is about to be "no limit" value :)

Additionaly, as I know - you don't need to set Form id, to allow using `multipart` parameter. Only if you updating your form via ajax, you have to set `Form.setOutputMarkupId(true)`. But actually, `Form` creates id by itself in `renderHead` method if it is multipart:

```
// register some metadata so we can later properly handle multipart ajax posts for
// embedded forms
registerJavaScriptNamespaces(response);
response
    .render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forScript("Wicket.Forms[\"" + getMarkupId()
        + "\"]={multipart:true};", Form.class.getName() + '.' + getMarkupId()
        + ".metadata"));
```

Note, that `getMarkupId()` method creates markup id if does not exists.

Comment: Wow, thanks Michael for you analysis. I see I can 'solve' this by setting the value to -1 or 0. Do you have any ideas why they would allow file uploads that are >2MB, but not ajax posts? Or is it so that `Wicket` sets the maxFormContentSize on the request if the form.setMaxSize() is used?

Comment: @RobAu, also, as I can see, if there is `multipart` request used, then jetty `Request` does not check `maxFormSize` by calling `extractMultipartParameters` method, and wicket `Form` can automatically detect if it is `multipart` or not in some cases (check `Form#isMultiPart` method). So, you can circumvent this limitation, even without knowing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a form size limit in Jetty defaulting to 200k.
Add a jetty-web.xml in your webapp/WEB-INF folder. There you can set a form size limit of the needed size.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"
  "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">

  <Configure id="WebAppContext" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
          <Set name="maxFormContentSize" type="int">900000</Set>
          <Set name="maxFormKeys">5000</Set>
  </Configure>
```

Comment: While this will probably solve my problem for jetty, I was hoping for a more structural answer, as file-uploads are not limited by this size. So they are transferred differently (but still using post) so I was hoping I could mimick this behaviour from the ajax-call somehow. I just don't know how or where to look